# Show that $u=y-p$ solves the differntial equation $u'-(2x+2p)u-u^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a general solution for the differential equation:
>
> $$y'-y^2-2xy=2$$
>
> 1. Show that $p(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ is a special solution
> 2. Show that $u(x)=y(x)-p(x)$ solves the differential equation $u'-(2x+2p)u-u^2=0$
> 3. Solve 2. by using a bernoulli substitution.

The first question is trivial. Plugging in $-\frac{1}{x}$ gives $2=2\checkmark$

For the second question I am not sure if I am supposed to solve $y'-y^2-2xy=2$ first and then use the solution to show that $y(x)-p(x)$ solves the differential equation in 2., or if there is some easier general way to show that $u(x)$ solves the equation.

Just plugging in $u$ doesn't seem to work

$$\begin{aligned}&u'=y'-p' \\& \implies (y'-p')-(2x+2p)(y-p)-u^2=0 \\ & \iff y'-p'-(2xy-2xp+2yp-2p^2)-(y^2-2py+p^2) \\& \iff y'-p'-2xy+2xp-2yp+2p^2-y^2+2py-p^2=0 \\& \iff y'-p'-2xy+2xp+p^2-y^2=0\end{aligned}$$

Then I tried to solve $y'-y^2-2xy=2$ first by using the typical Ricatti substitution $y(x)=f+\frac{1}{v}$

$$\begin{aligned}&y=-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{v} \implies y'=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{v^2}v' \\& \implies -v'-v(\frac{2}{x}+2x)+1=0 \\ & \iff v=\frac{e^{x^2}(x^2-1)+c}{2x^2e^{x^2}}\\& \implies y=\frac{2x^2e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2}(x^2-1)+c}-\frac{1}{x}\end{aligned}$$

Plugging $y$ and $p$ into the green equation becomes extremely messy and as far as I can tell doesn't satisfy the equation. Is there some easier method to do this?

Comment: When "just plugging $u$" you changed $2x+2p$ to $2x-2p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug $u$ into the 2nd equation correctly, respecting $2x+2p$. Then use that fact that the 1st equation holds and also use that $p = -1/x$.

Comment: @qmd, I see you've edited the question. Now $y′−p′−2xy+2xp+p^2−y^2$ is just one step from an identity.

Comment: Just another quick question: Doing everything correctly (hopefully) I get: $$y'-p'-2xy+2xp+p^2-y^2=0 \iff y'-\frac{1}{x^2}-2xy-2-\frac{1}{x^2}-y^2=0 \\ \iff y'-2xy-y^2=2$$

But what can I conclude from this result. How have I shown that $u$ satisfies the diff. equation. All I got was another differential equation. Shouldn't i be getting something like $2=2$ or $x=x$. Why can I assume that $y'-y^2...=2$ actually holds

Comment: I assume $y$ is a solution of the initial equation of this problem. So you can conclude from "this result" that $u=y-p$ solves that equation. I don't think an arbitrary $y$ would fit into the 2nd subproblem. I also think the statement of the problem could've been more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You should plug $u$ in the second equation and then use the fact that both $p$ and $y$ are solution of the first equation